# What are the differences between BaseClass vs. ClassMixin in sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn

In scikit-learn, what what are the meanings of BaseClass and ClassMixin, example: BaseEstimator and (ClassifierMixin, RegressorMixin)? Why not create a BaseClassifier and a BaseRegressor?

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/base.py

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that everything starts with `BaseEstimator`, which gives you `__repr__` etc, and then according to what you're trying to create, you use `TransformerMixin` if you want a `fit_transform` method, `ClassifierMixIn` if you want a `score` method, etc.